# How do I include this bottom action bar to my layout

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I include a bottom action bar into my `activity_main.xml` layout. The bottom action bar comes with a floating action button and both views have to be under the coordinator layout– Here it is:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabCradleMargin="0dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_app_bar_menu" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Layout for the `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
 
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
 
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
 
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
 
        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 
    </LinearLayout>
 
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_nav" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The `activity_main.xml` layout above includes a tab layout and a viewpager for swiping.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the `ConstraintLayout` to organize your whole `View`. The `BottomNavigationView` or `BottomAppBar` need to be inserted below the `Viewpager`. Follow along my code to see the hierarchy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" 
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigationView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_nav"/>
    
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In the result you see the `BottomNavigationView` (I added the menu to make sure you see something, like Fragment 1, Fragment 2 etc..):

[image: Inserted in your code]